# How do you disable the background of a slider and make the entire control a solid color?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, slider, windows-store-apps

I have a slider in a Windows Store app that is being used to zoom in and out of a map.

I want the background and foreground to be a solid gray color that will not change no matter where the little "tick" is located on the slider.

No matter what color settings I have tried to change, the slider always reverts to half being a solid blue color and the other half being the background color I want.

This is for a Windows Store 8.1 App with xaml views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to SO, let's solve your issue.

If we go look at the parts of the [default style template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709929.aspx) we can see what objects we need to go talk to in order to get your effect.

You'll be looking for the Brushes/Colors used in the different pieces like `Rectangle` and `Border` controls inside the template so you can override them explicitly, look through the defaults listed there and you'll find which parts to manipulate.

One piece that may stand out is how they have the `Background` and `Foreground` properties template bound to separate objects like;

```
<Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalTrackRect"
           Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
           Grid.Row="1"
           Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
<Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalDecreaseRect"
           Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
           Grid.Row="1" />
```

This is from the Horizontal template obviously but we see how the `TrackRect` spans all 3 columns and is accepting your `Background` property. However the `DecreaseRect` is just in the first cell and is accepting its property from `Foreground`

So the question I would give in response, is have you tried setting your color choice to both `Background` AND `Foreground` congruently? Give it a shot, worse comes to worse we just dig through the template some more and find the culprit. Hope this helps, Cheers.